# How would you create the data in table1 given the data in table2?

Tags: sql

I know SQL pretty well for joins and queries, but when it comes to this I have no idea. Can someone take a crack at this, please?

How would you create the data in table1 given the data in table2? Write an SQL query.

Table1 (csv):

```
order_id1, prod_id1
order_id1, prod_id2
order_id1, prod_id3
order_id1, prod_id4
order_id1, prod_id4
```

Table2 (csv):

```
order_id1, prod_id1, prod_id2, prod_id3, prod_id4, prod_id4
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for this kind of `INSERT` will vary depending upon the database platform you are using. The below works for SQL Server:

```
insert into table1
(order_id, prod_id)
select order_id1, prod_id1 from table2
union all
select order_id1, prod_id2 from table2
union all
select order_id1, prod_id3 from table2
union all
select order_id1, prod_id4 from table2
```

**Note:** You have two `prod_id4` columns in your example, so I left one out, assuming it is a mistake

Comment: Works on Oracle, MySQL, Postgresql, SQLite... :)

Answer (score 0):

no way, you got to do a script
coz you dont even know how many lines there are int the table1
if the number of lines is fixed, than you can do as RedFiter said
otherwise you may write procedure with a loop inside